# Regex match text after last '-'

Tags: regex

I am really stuck with the following regex problem:

I want to remove the last piece of a string, but only if the '-' is more then once occurring in the string.

Example:

BOL-83846-M/L -> Should match -M/L and remove it

B0L-026O1 -> Should not match

D&F-176954 -> Should not match

BOL-04134-58/60 -> Should match -58/60 and remove it

BOL-5068-4 - 6 jaar -> Should match -4 - 6 jaar and remove it (maybe in multiple search/replace steps)

It would be no problem if the regex needs two (or more) steps to remove it.
Now I have

```
[^-]*$
```

But in sublime it matches B0L-026O1 and D&F-176954

Need your help please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can match the first `-` in a capture group, and then match the second `-` till the end of the string to remove it.

In the replacement use capture group 1.

```php
^([^-\n]*-[^-\n]*)-.*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^-\n]*-[^-\n]*` Match the first `-` between chars other than `-` (or a newline if you don't want to cross lines)
- `)` Capture group 1
- `-.*$` Match the second `-` and the rest of the line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IDKj6T/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can match the following regular expression.

```
^[^-\r\n]*(?:$|-[^-\r\n]*(?=-|$))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VO1EMC/1)

If the string contains two or more hyphens this returns the beginning of the string up to, but not including, the second hyphen; else it returns the entire string.

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
^            # match the beginning of the string
[^-\r\n]*    # match zero or more characters other than hyphens,
             # carriage returns and linefeeds
(?:          # begin a non-capture group
  $          # match the end of the string
|            # or
  -          # match a hyphen
  [^-\r\n]*  # match zero or more characters other than hyphens,
             # carriage returns and linefeeds
  (?=        # begin a positive lookahead
    -        # match a hyphen
    |        # or
    $        # match the end of the string
  )          # end positive lookahead
)            # end non-capture group
```